# How register UDF without arguments in Apache Spark by Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I need to register udf function without arguments. But Apache Spark have not UDF0 interface realization.
I trying somethig like:

```
UDF1<Object, String> my_func = o -> return "some_generated_string";
sqlContext.udf().register("my_func", my_func, DataTypes.StringType);
```

But `df.withColumns("newCol", functions.expr("concat(col1, my_funct())"));` returns exception `org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration$$anonfun$register$25$$anonfun$apply$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function0`.

So `df.withColumns("newCol", functions.expr("concat(col1, my_funct(1))"));` work correctly but this is wrong way and smells bad.

*UDFRegistration* in *org.apache.spark.sql* has method `register[RT: TypeTag](name: String, func: Function0[RT]): UserDefinedFunction`. Java see this method as `register(String name, Function0<RT> func, TypeTag<RT> evidence$1)`. I can wrote *scala.Function0* implementation, but what is **TypeTag evidence$1**?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this problem by next trick:

```
UDF1<Object, String> my_func = o -> "some_generated_string";
sqlContext.udf().register("my_func", my_func, DataTypes.StringType);

String expression = "concat(`col1`, my_func())";
expression = expression.replace("my_func()", "my_func(null)");

df.withColumns("newCol", functions.expr(expression));
```